# How to convert config/environment.js to CoffeeScript?

Tags: ember-cli

Using ember-cli version 0.2.3, I converted `config/environment.js` to `config/environment.coffee`.

The app is named `frontend`.

In the `dist/frontend.js` file, I see the following differences - note that instead of `frontend`, the prefix is `undefined`.

How to fix this?

Working:

```
define('frontend/config/environment', ['ember'], function(Ember) {
  var prefix = 'frontend';
  ...
```

Not working:

```
define('undefined/config/environment', ['ember'], function(Ember) {
  var prefix = 'undefined';
  ...
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?